# Failure to run network command in Stata for network meta-analysis (mixed treatment comparison)

Tags: stata

I am trying unsuccessfully to run the `network` and ancillary commands in Stata for network meta-analysis, as provided by Chaimani et al here:

http://www.mtm.uoi.gr/index.php/stata-routines-for-network-meta-analysis

I am using Stata 13, and I have already installed the mvmeta and indirect packages, as well as any other potentially pertinent package. Yet, despite this, when I run the examples provided in the help file of the network graphs (typing `help network graphs` in Stata), they do not run correctly or at all (see the complete Stata script and screenshot below).

```
use http://www.mtm.uoi.gr/images/antihypertensives.dta, clear

network setup r n, stud(id) trt(t) num ref(1)

network meta c

intervalplot, eform pred null(1) lab(Placebo BB Diuretics CCB ACE ARB) sep marg(10 40 5 5) notab

netleague, lab(Placebo BB Diuretics CCB ACE ARB) sort(ARB ACE Placebo CCB BB Diuretics) eform

network rank min,zero all reps(10000) gen(prob)

sucra prob*, lab(Placebo BB Diuretics CCB ACE ARB) rankog

intervalplot, lab(Placebo BB Diuretics CCB ACE ARB) noplot notab keep

split _Comparison, par(“ vs ”) gen(t)

mdsrank _Effect_Size _Standard_Error t1 t2 if _Effect_Size!=.,best(max)

use http://www.mtm.uoi.gr/images/antidiabetics_efficacy_long.dta, clear

network setup y sd n, stud(id) trt(t) ref(1) num

network meta c

network rank min,zero all reps(10000) gen(tol_prob)

sucra tol_prob*, lab(Placebo Sulfonylurea "DPP-4 inhibitor" Thiazolidinedione "GLP-1 analog" AGI Glinine) noplot
```

[image: Stata screenshot]

What should I do? Am I missing a specific package? Or is there something wrong with the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the package containing the `network` commands. Follow the instructions under "How to obtain the routines" in the link you provided to install the packages described in that document, which build on the packages you have already installed, or else issue the Stata command `help network setup` to install the packages via the SSC archive.